# Use dynamic column name in spark

Tags: apache-spark, databricks

I am coding Python in Databricks and I am using spark 2.4.5.

I have function like below code :

```
def verifyMatchAndDisplayDifferences(oldDF, newDF, pkColumn):
   ...
   newDF.join(oldDF, newDF.SK_ID_Site == oldDF.SK_ID_Site, "full")
   ...
```

As you can see i am joinning two Dataframe by using a column (SK_ID_Site).
I would like to know how can i use my paramettre (pkColumn) instead of using hard coded column name?

I tried below code but it did not work

```
newDF.join(oldDF, newDF.col(pkColumn) == oldDF.col(pkColumn), "full")
```

Answer (score 3):

Since, it is always the same key you can use the `on` parameter

```
def verifyMatchAndDisplayDifferences(oldDF, newDF, pkColumn):
   ...
   newDF.join(oldDF, on=[pkColumn], how="full")
   ...
```

More documentation here, https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/dataframe.html#DataFrame.join

Comment: If i have composite pkColumns what do I have to do? and what if my pkColumn is a litilebit different. for exemple PK_Site and PK_Site_Old? i have a pattern and i can create pk column name in my function. because of that i passed just one parameter.